# Data warehousing in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, data-warehouse

I am new to data warehousing and I am a little confused.

Please provide some simple steps to create a cube and fill it and make query on it

To know :

- I have a database with the original data and I have designed the star schema and made appropriate tables
- I have created an analysis service project in VS 2008 and then I have made the data source -data source view-dimensions - and the cube all that based on the star schema I have created previously

Now what should I do to:

- fill this cube
- make query on this cube

Comment: The question is vague - Are you asking how to populate the data warehouse? If so look at SSIS and its uses in ETL, to query a cube you'd use MDX as a query language, or connect to it via Excel and treat it as a pivot table. Try and be more precise in what you're asking :)

Comment: +1 cause even is the question is vague he has done a lot of the work already

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a pretty good tutorial **[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx)**, and for MDX **[see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500184.aspx)**.

In SSAS, filling-in data into a cube is called **processing** cube, measure, dimension...
See **[details here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174860.aspx)**.

Tutorials are fairly long, so I do not think that a generic answer would fit here,  I would suggest that you work you way through tutorials and then return with more focused, specific questions.